# Why does Meteor update a record without running a "Meteor.call" to update?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I am working on a Meteor.js app and I've gotten a hang of Meteor per se, but maybe I'm misunderstanding something about its principle of reactivity or haven't read about it enough.

I'm using angular-meteor and I have access to a $scope variable in my view which is a `$meteor.object`. I was creating a form to update this record and I had started wiring up a "Save" button with an `ng-click` to update the record. `Meteor.call('update', {})`, for example. But as I was adding the input fields and changing the values in the inputs I noticed that the changes were persisting. The update method inside the `Collection.allow` method is being called and the record is updating.

Is this supposed to be happening this way?

Comment: yes. Method calls are only needed for more explicit server interactions. The most common interaction is through the collections, which are synced automatically. That is what makes meteor so easy to work with: no rest api or anything just to move data around.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Method calls are only needed for more explicit server interactions. The most common interaction is through the collections, which are synced automatically. That is what makes meteor so easy to work with: no rest api or anything just to move data around.

Comment: That's pretty awesome. Thank you. So I guess Method calls are more for creating and deleting records while updates are synced automatically? And are there any gotchas to look out for with the automatic syncing?

Comment: you create and delete records using `insert` and `remove` on the client-side collection (and that gets synched automatically). methods are for all the other things, like kicking of batch jobs on the server, or running some server side code and returning the result..